# From Stata to R: recoding bysort and xtreg

Tags: r, replication, stata

I'm very new to R and currently working on a replication project for a meta-research course at my university. The paper examines if having a in-home display to monitor energy consumption reduces the energy usage. I have already recoded 300 lines of code, but now I ran into a problem I could not yet solve.

The source code says: `bysort id expdays: egen ave15 = mean(power) if hours0105==1`

I do understand what this does, but I cannot replicate it in R. `id` is the identifier for the examined household and `expdays` denotes the current day of the experiment. So `ave15` is the average power consumption from midnight to 6 am sorted for every household on each day. I figured out that (EIPbasedata is the complete dataset containing hourly data)

`EIPbasedata$ave15[EIPbasedata$hours0105 == 1] <- ave(EIPbasedata$power, EIPbasedata$ID, EIPbasedata$ExpDays, FUN=mean)`

would probably do the job, but this gives me a warning:

`number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length`

and the results are not right too. I do not have any idea what I could do to solve this.

The next thing I struggle to recode is:

`xtreg  ln_power0105 ihd0105 i.days0105 if exptime==4, fe vce(bootstrap, rep(200) seed(12345))`

I think the right way would be using `plm` but I'm not sure how to implement the `if` condition (`days0105` is a running variable for the number of the day in experiment and 0 if not between 0-6am, `ihd0105` is a dummy for having an in-home display, `exptime` denotes 4 am in the morning- however I do not understand what `exptime` does here)

`table4_1 <-  plm(EIPbasedata$ln_power0105 ~ EIPbasedata$ihd0105, data=EIPbasedata, index = c("days0105"), model="within")`

How do I compute the bootstrapped standard errors in `plm`?

I hope some expert can help me, since my R and Stata knowledge is not sufficient for this..

Comment: For `bysort id expdays: egen ave15 = mean(power) if hours0105==1`, try something like `library(dplyr); df %>% group_by(id, expdays) %>% mutate(ave15 = mean(power[hours0105 == 1]))`

Comment: `EIPbasedata <- EIPbasedata %>% group_by(ID, ExpDays) %>% mutate(ave15 = mean(power[hours0105 == 1]))` did work like a charm, now I just need to get the plm working

Comment: In your `xtreg` line, the if-condition is a filter in the sense that the regression is carried out on the subset of the data, right? It would seem that filtering the data is then appropriate, e.g. using `subset(df, exptime==4)`.

Comment: Thats the problem, I do not know what the if condition does, because my knowledge of Stata is very limited. The code is not commented and the paper itself does not highlight this. Also, playing around with `plm` I just found out that the `ave15` vector was not filled completely. The `plm` throws errors because `NA/NaN/Inf in 'y'` and after the last `hours0105` part there are some `NaN` in `ave15` values. This is due to the fact, that the dataset of the last household does start at 1p.m. and therefore  the dplyr cannot fill the vector completely. any idea how to deal with the `NaN in y` error?

Comment: Well, if I want to run a regression and a household has no data on the variables I care about, I would probably exclude it from my dataset.

Comment: I replaced all `NaN` with NAs and omitted those in the regression, which is running fine now. However the results are of course not matching those in the paper, since I wasn't able to include the `exptime==4`.

Comment: What's wrong with subset?

Comment: I've found the answer to the problem, there are probably better and cleaner ways to do this, but I'm fine with it for now. However, thank you for your help with the `dplyr` method, coffeinjunky!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My lecturer provided the answer to me: at first i do specify a subsample which I call `tmp_data` here: `tmp_data <- EIPbasedata[which(EIPbasedata$ExpTime == 4) , ]`

Then I'm regressing the tmp_data with `as.factor(days0105)` values, which is the R equivalent to `i.days0105`

`tmp_results <- plm(tmp_data$ln_power0105 ~ tmp_data$ihd0105 + as.factor(tmp_data$days0105), data = tmp_data, index = ("ID"), model = "within")`

There are probably better and cleaner ways to do this, but I'm fine with it for now.